# "...at that" expression: meaning

Tags: word-usage

In the sentence:

> "They wonder why music is being played so late at night - and in a museum **at that**."

what does ***"at that"*** mean, what role does it play here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **[at that](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/that#at-that)**: "used after adding a remark that makes what you had said before even more extreme".

Comment: I quoted it from Macmillan Dictionary. You can click on the word "at that" in my comment above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "at that" is used to express that not only it is unexpected that loud music is being heard late at night, but that it is particularly unexpected that the loud music is coming from a museum.